# Modeling a viscoelastic string with a collection of damped spring oscillators? (To replace finite difference model.) How to find $Q$ per harmonic?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, resonance, viscosity, dissipation

## Background

I have simulated a vibrating viscoelastic string fixed at each end under tension using finite difference modeling. Most simply this can be done using Kelvin-Voigt style mass-spring dampers as the units such as these:

[image]

Where for each unit stress in terms of strain is described as $σ = Eε + ηε_t$.

This works well. However, it is very computationally expensive to get high resolution.

## Goal

I would like to next take a simpler approach of visualizing the string as a series of summed damped mass-spring oscillators (one for each harmonic). Or perhaps equivalently (if it can be thought of as so) as a single damped mass-spring oscillator which is being pushed into forced oscillations for the higher harmonics relative to the fundamental.

Certainly it is no trouble setting up oscillators at the appropriately spaced frequencies, even accounting for the string's possible inharmonicity in their positioning.

However, then one must try to calculate the equivalent damping (Q) of each partial as we go up the frequencies relative to the Q or decay rate of the fundamental and I am not sure how that would work.

## Oscillator Basics

For a single damped spring mass oscillator we have the following relationships:

Undamped frequency:
$ω_0 = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$

Damped frequency:
$ω =  \sqrt{ω_0^2 - {\frac{b}{2m}}^2}$

Velocity at any given $x$ compared to the max $A$ of an undamped osc:
$|v|=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}(A^2−x^2)}$

Amplitude of forced oscillations for a given input force:
$A=\frac{F_0}{\sqrt{m^2(ω^2−ω_0^2)^2+b^2ω^2}}$

Amplitude of the fundamental for a given input force:
$A_{max}=\frac{F_0}{bω_0}$

## Q: The Missing Piece

The only guidance I can find on how any of it might work in terms of Q is the line: "For a small damping, the quality is approximately equal to $Q=mω_0b$." But this only covers the fundamental frequency.

What about the forced or higher harmonics in the model?

Certainly higher frequencies decay faster than lower ones with a constant damping factor on the units in FDM. This is also also obvious in nature. (Eg. higher harmonics of a guitar string decay faster than lower even if excited equally which is audible and visible.)

I am mostly interested in the underdamped case where there is only small damping.

## Question:

- If it is valid to think of the string as a single mass-spring damped oscillator (representing the fundamental) and then expect the harmonics to act as if the unit is being forced into higher frequency resonances, how could one predict the Q of the higher frequencies given a certain setup on the fundamental?
- Alternatively, if one must instead think of the harmonics as completely distinct mass-spring damped oscillators, how could one parameterize them to decay similarly to the Kelvin-Voigt finite difference model? ie. How can one set the Q to replicate the higher frequency decays given a given fundamental configuration?

## Most Simply...

I would essentially just like to know how to predict the decay Q of the higher resonances in a configuration where we are expecting the same output as the the Kelvin-Voigt FDM system given an excitation.

This has puzzled me for a long time. It is important to something I've been working on for a while. I'm sure there must be a way, but I don't have the knowledge base or education to know. Thanks for any thoughts or ideas. I appreciate anything.

## References

- [https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-*Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves*(OpenStax)/15%3A_Oscillations/15.06%3A_Damped_Oscillations](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Oscillations/15.06%3A_Damped_Oscillations)
- https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/15-2-energy-in-simple-harmonic-motion
- https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/15-6-forced-oscillations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Longitudinal waves**

You can calculate the harmonics in the continuum limit. You can look at longitudinal waves in a viscoelastic material by looking at longitudinal displacement $u(x,t)$. Then the strain is:
$$
\epsilon=\partial_xu
$$ and the equation of motion is:
$$
\rho\partial_t^2 u=\partial_x(E\partial_x u+\eta\partial_{tx}u)
$$
with $\rho$ the mass density and $E$ the Young modulus. If your string has fixed ends, and $x$ goes from $0$ to $L$, then you also need to add Dirichlet boundary conditions:
$$
u(x=0,L)=0
$$
The harmonics are indexed by $n\in\mathbb N^*$
$$
h_n=\sin(k_nx)\\
k_n=\frac{\pi n}L
$$
With the reconstruction formula:
$$
u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_nh_n\frac{2}{L}\\
u_n=\int_0^Lu(x)h_ndx
$$
Each mode coefficient behaves as a damped harmonic oscillator:
$$
\rho\ddot u_n=-k_n^2(Eu_n+\eta\dot u_n)
$$
so you can identify:
$$
\ddot u_n+2\zeta_n \omega_n\dot u_n+\omega_n^2u_n=0\\
\omega_n=k_n\sqrt\frac E\rho\\
\zeta_n=\frac{k_n\eta}{2\sqrt{\rho E}}
$$
and get the quality factor $Q=\frac1{2\zeta}$:
$$
Q_n=\frac{\sqrt{\rho E}}{k_n\eta}
$$
Even if you’re interested in the underdamped case, it cannot be valid uniformly for all harmonics. No matter the choice of the macroscopic parameters $E,\rho,\eta,L$, the high harmonics will always be overdamped as $Q_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. The threshold index is:
$$
N =\frac{2L}{\pi\eta}\sqrt{\rho E}
$$
For $n<N$ the harmonics are underdamped and for $n>N$ the harmonics are overdamped. Btw, since $N$ is an integer, you can have all the harmonics that are underdamped when:
$$
\frac{2L}{\pi\eta}\sqrt{\rho E}<1
$$

**String**

In the case of a string with only longitudinal displacements, this is equivalent to the previous analysis:
$$
\epsilon = \sqrt{(1+u_x)^2}-1 \\
\sigma = \sigma_0+E\epsilon+\eta \epsilon_t
$$
so the exact equation of motion is:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho u_{tt} &= \left(\sigma \frac{\partial\epsilon}{\partial u_x}\right)_x \\
&= \sigma_x \\
&= Eu_{xx}+\eta u_{tx}
\end{align}
$$
so an additional background tension does not change anything. Indeed, this is the same reason that in continuum mechanics, pressure is determined up to an additive constant.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am incredibly grateful for your answer. It was very courteous of you to include the critical damping cutoff solution as well. I realize now I was not specific in my OP that I am actually looking for a solution to the transverse waves. I also didn't provide an equation of motion to demonstrate. But this was perhaps good, as your answer for the simpler case of the longitudinal vibrations was highly instructive and it helped me think a bit more about how the transverse case might work. I am very glad to have it.

Comment: I posted a new question on the transverse case as it raises more complex questions. I would love to hear any even casual thoughts you might have bout whether it could be solvable or approximated or how: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/798202/solving-the-decay-q-of-transverse-waves-in-a-viscoelastic-string-based-on-this Any thoughts you'd have at all (even speculative) would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: I notice just one minor possible issue: I think $ρ$ is actually not the linear mass density here, but rather the mass density. Right? As in http://kapitaniak.kdm.p.lodz.pl/papers/2014/Marynowski_Kapitaniak.pdf the wave equation (transverse) is generally $ρw_{tt} = (σ + \frac{T}{A})w_{xx}$ where as they state in that article, $ρ$ is mass density (in their article, they use $ρ_l=ρA$ as linear density). The same for $ρ$ should apply longitudinally I presume in equivalent terms?

Comment: Also, I have run simulations since yesterday using your math. It has been very helpful. Longitudinal waves while not my primary interest are very interesting still. I wonder, does adding a baseline tension term (like in the Marynowski equation above) to the string affect the equations in any way? Where might that go in your equations if so? If it in any way affects anything through the equations, I would be very grateful to see it added so I can play with it too. Thanks again for all your ideas. They have been brilliant.

Comment: Glad it helped! It's rare to get such enthusiastic feedback